# Python try except - Include the custom message in the Error variable

Tags: python, try-except

Im trying to do a simple try except, and it is working. But I want to add some custom string at the beginning of the error message. If I just add it in print, its giving error.

```
import sys

try:
    with open('./datatype-mapping/file.json') as rs_mapping:
         data_mapping = json.load(rs_mapping)
except Exception as error:
        print('CUSTOM ERROR: '+error)
        sys.exit(1)
```

The error I got is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 22, in get_datatype_mapping
    with open('./datatype-mapping/file.json') as rs_mapping:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './datatype-mapping/file.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 99, in main
    target_mapping()
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 39, in target_mapping
    data_mapping = get_datatype_mapping()
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 26, in get_datatype_mapping
    print('ERROR: '+error)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "FileNotFoundError") to str
```

But if I use just `print(error)` - this is working.

Comment: Python doesn't have a concept of type-coercion, this why concatenating a `Exception` to a `str` doesn't make a `Exception` turn into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `error` to `str`.

```py
import sys

try:
  int("fail")
except Exception as error:
  print('CUSTOM ERROR: ' + str(error))
  sys.exit(1)
```

This works flawlessly.